# Programmatically read email from inbox on iPhone

Tags: ios, email

Is it possible for my iOS app to access the user's email inbox in the Mail app? I would like to be able to read the emails and save the attachments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Apple doesn't provide an API for that.

However, you're free to ask the user for their mail server settings and then talk directly to an IMAP server, downloading the attachments yourself.

If you have presets for popular email providers (MobileMe, Gmail, Yahoo, etc.) this won't have to be too difficult for most users to deal with.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so you mean essentially you need to implement your own email stack to do this?

Comment: Yup. Though if you only want read-only access (to get at attachments), that should simply things a lot.