# Can i copy/move email from (IOS mail) to my application?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4

I am creating app in which i want to copy/move (IOS mail) to my application.Can anybody tell me is this possible to copy or move an IOS mail to my application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756103/is-that-possible-to-programmatically-read-email-from-inbox-on-iphone

Answer (score 0):

You cant access mails from inbuilt Mail iOS app.
At least not from any public method since Apple does not provide it. Dont know about private methods

Comment: thanx for your positive response.i think you are right.i have already RND on that from 2 days but not  succeeded.thanx again

Comment: There is not any private API available for non-jail broken iPhone except jail broken iPhone.